# How to have multiple web configs in single application

Tags: html, asp.net, web-config

I have my login page, and 2 separate modules other then my login page. After login, it sends you to the login page  with the links unhidden. The links only become available after your role has been confirmed. **My question is** how do I link my 2 separate webconfigs to my separate modules. I was told I could do this straight on the webconfig file without adding the Page_Load event in C#. If that’s true can I get an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should adds two connection string declare in web.config. Because Web.Config not unalterable in runtime.  Choose connection string as need.

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="dbConnectionString1" connectionString=""/>
<add name="dbConnectionString2" connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Or get the connection string from different database. You create function to get connection string method. Function get connection string as need. Or return static connection string. For example:

```
public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        if ()
            return "connectionstring1";
        else
            return "connectionstring2";
    }
```